# regex to replace anything that is not a number or period in string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, function, ecmascript-6

I am trying to write a regex that replaces anything that isn't a digit or a `.` in a string.

For example:

```
const string = 'I am a 1a.23.s12h31 dog'`
const result = string.replace(/[09.-]/g, '');
// result should be `1.23.1231`
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: `.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, '')`? See https://regex101.com/r/WiQ8as/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your regex to `[^0-9.]+`:

```
const result = string.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, "");
```

Alternatively, if you don't want a regex, use `split` and `filter`, then `join`:

```
const result = string.split("").filter(s => isNaN(s) || s == ".").join("");
```